# Can I use the word "duration" for an ongoing event which has no estimated end?

Tags: word-usage, time

Can I use the word "duration" for an ongoing event which has no estimated end?

An example: "The duration of this rain is 25 minutes". It started 25 minutes ago, and it is still raining.

Comment: Duration implies a start and an end.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duration - *It’s been raining for the last 25 minutes, and it is still raining.*

Comment: 'Duration' is a word used almost solely in formal registers {'The dashed lines are postal survey 95% confidence bounds on mean outbreak durations.'
 [Cambridge English Corpus] ... 'A second phonetic factor is the frequent lengthening of phrasefinal segments, which results in longer closure durations among stops.' [Cambridge English Corpus]}, so your everyday example sounds distinctly odd even before one looks at semantic correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Edwin notes in comments, *duration* is less common in everyday conversation than, say, the verb *last*. I would say "I didn't see a weather report, so I don't know how long this storm will last" rather than than "... so I don't know this storm's predicted duration." However, I might say "I don't know how long the opera is, but we'll stay for the duration," meaning all of it  / its entirety.

Your example in everyday conversation would likely be:

> It's been raining for 25 minutes.

Which means it is still raining.

To emphasize a period of (ongoing) time you can say:

> The blizzard has lasted 20 hours so far.

---

> **duration** (n.)
>
> Lasting, continuance in time; the continuance or length of time; the time during which a thing, action, or state continues.
> (OED)

> **Duration** is how long something lasts, from beginning to end.
> [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/duration)

In more formal settings where *duration* is appropriate, I believe you need to qualify it when referring to the elapsed time of an **ongoing event**, for example:

> You can control whether changes to total percent complete are
> distributed through the status date or to the end of the task's actual
> **duration so far.** [Microsoft; "Percent (%) Complete fields"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/percent-complete-fields-84ec5068-4a34-497c-97eb-e12b6dc47cc5)

> Second, the "**duration so far**" statistics do not say how much longer
> those unemployed remained unemployed. Indeed, it turns out that
> "**duration so far**" is a very poor indicator of the duration of
> completed spells. [International Labour Office; *Growth, Structural
> Change, and Manpower Policy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Growth_Structural_Change_and_Manpower_Po/4Br4xUiCEREC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22duration%20so%20far%20statistics%22&dq=%22duration%20so%20far%20statistics%22&printsec=frontcover) (1979)

> Here is an example. Suppose that we are in a bull market. We have
> advanced 67.6%; the **duration so far** is 880 calendar days; we are
> in the fourth leg. [Arthur Merrill; *Behavior of Prices on Wall
> Street*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Behavior_of_Prices_on_Wall_Street/wEsUAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22duration%20so%20far%20is%22&dq=%22duration%20so%20far%20is%22&printsec=frontcover) (1966)

> Figure 2 gives the results for the test UO<sub>2</sub> fragments at 7 ppm
> initial [U]. The **total duration so far** is 800 days. It seems that
> the precipitation of a secondary phase has started. [V. Oversby and L. Werme; *Scientific Basis
> for Nuclear Waste Management*, vol.27, p.50](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Scientific_Basis_for_Nuclear_Waste_Manag/9QFFAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22duration%20so%20far%20is%22&dq=%22duration%20so%20far%20is%22&printsec=frontcover)  (2004)

---

> So, a task with a baseline duration of 10 days and an actual
> **duration to date** of 3 days is 30 percent complete. [Nancy Mingus; *Alpha Teach Yourself Project Management in 24 Hours*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alpha_Teach_Yourself_Project_Management/OdHUH71lmnIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22duration%20to%20date%22&pg=PA261&printsec=frontcover) (2001)

> Actual duration ratio percent complete, which is calculated by
> dividing actual **duration to date** by at-completion duration. [Saleh
> Mubarak; *Construction Project Scheduling and Control*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Construction_Project_Scheduling_and_Cont/H9GkDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22duration%20to%20date%22&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> For those currently employed, the unemployment duration is recorded as *x<sub>i</sub>*. For those still unemployed, the duration is recorded as
> *y<sub>i</sub>*, the **duration to date**. [Nathan Sinai; *For the Disabled Sick*, Issues 5-0, p.48](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Guide_to_Econometrics/69MDEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22duration%20to%20date%22&pg=PA470&printsec=frontcover) (1949)

---

> Present perfect (progressive):
> I have been living here for three
> years. [***Duration up to now:** I am still living here.*] [Barbara
> Robinson; *Focus Workbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Focus_Workbook/0K7Jeaq7nPUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22duration%20up%20to%20now%22&pg=PA99&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

> The time reference may take two forms: in looking back from his
> viewpoint, the observer may specify either the beginning of the state
> or habit or its **duration up to now**. [Günter Radden and ‎René Dirven;
> *Cognitive English Grammar*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cognitive_English_Grammar/lx7UAniLfJwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22duration%20up%20to%20now%22&pg=PA216&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

Comment: I agree. Can you find a similar example in a dictionary? // I'd start here by querying OP's use of 'duration' in a conversational register.